# Cast List<object> to List<string>

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I've spent way to much time on trying to resolve this and I don't understand why I can't cast this. I'm executing a query and pulling all the values from a specific column that is then stored in a List since it could be an int, string, or bool. The issue is during casting, I would like a dynamic solution that can validate the object type and cast accordingly.

```
//This handles the db connection and makes calls DbItems class
    public List<object> GetDBColumns(string sqlQuery, string column)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var reader = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection).ExecuteReader();
                    var values = DbItems.GetColumns(reader, column);
                    connection.Close();
                    return values;
                }
            }

Public class DbItems
{

 DbItems(SqlDataReader reader, string column)
    {   //GetInt32 won't be able to handle other types of course, what could I use?
        columnData.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal(column)));
    }

    List<object> columnData = new List<object>();

    //I'm calling this static method that invokes the constructor 
    public static List<object> GetColumns(SqlDataReader reader, string column)
        {
            List<object> dataSet = new List<object>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dataSet.Add(new DbItem(reader, column).columnData);
            }
            return dataSet;
        }
    }
```

This works without issue, but then I'll get an int value that I'd like to cast a string and I've used Cast<>, (string)columnData[0], and a couple other suggestions online and nothing works. Please assist.

Comment: Because that would allow you to obtain `some_list[0]` as a string, whereas there are *no* guarantees that those are actually `string`s.

Comment: Furthermore converting could fail, and there can be several "reasonable" conversions. So what one should be picked in that case?

Comment: Casting is not for converting one type to another. For converting, you can try something like `var stringList = dataSet.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString);`

Comment: Possible typo: should `DbRow` be `DbItems`? Unrelated tips: SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are both IDisposable so should each be in a using block. The connection doesn't need to be closed because the implicit Dispose on exiting that using block will close it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Casting `List<object>` to `List<string>` would require [contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index) of `List`'s generic parameter `T`. Unfortunatelly `List<T>` does not meet criteria for contravariance, because it is not an *interface*, *delegate* or *array* type, and because making it's generic parameter contravariant wouldn't be type-safe (doing so would e.g. allowed `List<string>` to contain not only strings, but any other object, which is obviously nonsence, not type-safe and therefore not allowed). Fot this reason, **you cannot cast `List<object>` to `List<string>`**.

What you can, however, is to create new `List<string>` and copy there all items from original `List<object>`, while converting each item to string. Item conversion with `Cast<>` or `(string)columnData[0]` will not work here (unless items are actually a `string`s), because casting a *reference-type* object to another *reference-type* only performs assignment compatibility check, but **does not perform any conversion of the object**.

Luckily, converting to `string` is trivial, since all objects inherits `.ToString()` method from `Object` type. So you can convert to `List<string>` with the following:

```
List<string> stringList = columnData.ConvertAll(item => item?.ToString());
```

But of course, you can use any other conversion, if `.ToString()` does not meet your needs, such as using [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to perform conversion between primitive types.

Comment: Using that convert method returns "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" instead of , "165"

Comment: @sysofadown3: It looks like you are calling conversion methon on a `List<object>`, whose items are another `List<object>`s (let's call them sublists), because calling `.ToString()` on a (sub)list returns it's type name, i.e. *"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Object]"*. Is it intentional? Or do you want to convert each sublist to a `string`? If you e.g. want to convert just a first item of each of these sublists to a `string`, this should do a job: `someList.ConvertAll(item => (item as List<object>)?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString())`. If you want something else, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so would be just call the `ToString` Method, since all object have a `ToString` Method

```
var values = columnData.Select(x => x?.ToString()).ToList();
```